# Как изменить данные QGraphicsProxyWidget?

Tags: c++, qt5, указатели, область-видимости

Я создал QGraphicsProxyWidget на QGraphicsScene. И хочу чтобы по нажатию она меняла картинку(иконку).

```
NewScene::NewScene(QObject *parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
    //добавляем кнопку
    QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton("Запуск");
    QGraphicsProxyWidget* wgt = this->addWidget(btn);
    btn->setIcon(QIcon(":/new/prefix1/Items/knife-switch-off.png")); //добавляем картинку
    btn->setIconSize(QSize(65, 65));
    wgt->setX(-200);
    wgt->setY(0);
    //событие кнопки
    QObject::connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [ = ]() {this->QCalcColission();});
}

void NewScene::QCalcColission()
{
    // меняем иконку кнопки
    this->btn->setIcon(QIcon(":/new/prefix1/Items/knife-switch-on.png"));
}
```

Вот тут при нажатии происходит ошибка - программа вылетает:

> Программа неожиданно завершилась.

Если не писать `this->btn->setIcon(QIcon(":/new/prefix1/Items/knife-switch-on.png"));`, а сделать, например, всплывающее окно, то ошибки нет.

Так что загвоздка именно в том, что я неправильно обновляю виджет.

Возможно нужен какой-то метод который его обновит , но какой? Или это вообще иначе делается?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что указатель btn "виден" только в локальной область видимости конструктора.
Чтобы кнопка была доступна в любом методе класса надо сделать ее полем класса:

```
class NewScene : public QGraphicsScene {
private:
    QPushButton* btn;
}
```

Теперь создаем кнопку в конструкторе:

```
NewScene::NewScene(QObject *parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
    //добавляем кнопку
    btn = new QPushButton("Запуск");
    ...
}
```

Далее, в любом методе класса, в частности:

```
void NewScene::QCalcColission()
{
    // меняем иконку кнопки
    this->btn->setIcon(QIcon(":/new/prefix1/Items/knife-switch-on.png"));
}
```

Вообще, получение в консоли `QtCreator` сообщения типа `Программа неожиданно завершилась` - верный признак того, что где-то осуществляется вызов метода у несуществующего, или неправильно созданного объекта, или указателя.

Comment: Вы мой спаситель